# Why i am not being able to delete topic using Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am using zookeeper version 3.5.8. when I delete a topic using the zookeeper delete topic command, it throws an error:

[image]

Comment: What is the full command that you tried?

Comment: You have a mismatch of version somewhere I think. The version of zookeeper you are using way wait for another version of Kafka ? Else it's an internal issue of Zookeeper, and you can submit it to them for advice.

Comment: @H.Ç.T kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic test

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I am using 2.5 version of  Kafka

Answer (score 1):

Latest Kafka CLI has deprecated Zookeeper flag. Please use `kafka-topics --bootstrap-server` instead, as shown in the Kafka documentation

You should also use the Zookeeper version bundled with Kafka since that's what it is tested against